# Fazer o click em uma <tr> abrir um link

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, mvc

No site que estou fazendo tem a necessidade de que quando for clicado em um linha da tabela ele redireciona para uma outra pagina, mas os id's da linha são dinâmico, pois cada linha deve redirecionar para uma pagina que mostra mais informações.

Minha View:

```
@foreach (projeto1.Entidade.PessoaEntidade item in Model)
        {
            <tr id="linha_@item.id">
                <td id="itemid_@item.id" style="width:10%">
                    @item.id
                </td>
                <td style="width:40%">
                    @item.Nome
                </td>
                <td style="width:40%">
                    @item.Sobrenome
                </td>
                <td style="width:10%">
                    <input type="button" value="Alterar" id="partionalViewUpdate" onclick="Teste(@item.id)" />
                </td>
            </tr>
```

Meu Script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("tr").click(function () {
           alert("Clicado");
    });
});
```

Comment: @Marconi não entendi a solução, sou inexperiente ainda em programação :P mas obrigado pela ajuda

Answer (score 3):

Use o `window.location` e concatene com o ID da sua `tr`:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("tr").click(function () {
          window.location = 'suaPagina.aspx?id=' + $(this).attr('id');
    });
});
```

Comment: Deu certo, muito obrigado!!

Answer (score 2):

Coloca um data-href na tr e um script

HTML

```
<tr data-href="http://www.example.com.br/link"></tr>
```

Script

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

  $("tr").click(function() {
    var url = $(this).attr("data-href");
    window.open(url);
  });

 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Não gosto muito de misturar javascript com Razor, mas tenta apenas incluir essa função no seu script, substituindo a action e o controller do método Url.Action pelo o que você ta querendo redirecionar.

```
function Teste(id)
{
      window.location = '@Url.Action("Action","Controller")?id=' + id;
}
```